# Starteam "Unknown" files

Tags: starteam

We have a StarTeam view that has two files that are in the "Unknown" state – does anyone understand why they are in this state and/or how we can get them out of the state?

Is deleting them and re-adding them with a different name the only solution?

Note that if you check out these two files (regularly or using “force checkout”), they will always be listed as “Unknown” (annoying).

Thanks.

---

More info based on Craig's suggestions below:

a) Calculating file status using MD5 checksum: same results ("Unknown" status)

b) These two files in question have only one revision on the server.  I'm not sure if this is because our CM group attempted to fix the issue by deleting and recreating the files or if there really was just one revision.  The files are text files.

c) I tried deleting the files on my local machine and refreshing the status.  When I do this, instead of seeing the two files listed as "Unknown", I see a total of four files listed with a status of "Missing".  There are two entries listed for each file - each pair has the same file name, folder path, "modified by", and "file stamp at time of check in".  I have no idea why each file is listed twice.  If I select each entry in a pair and select "Compare Contents", my diff tool says they are identical.

I have this same weird issue with the four files whether I use the MD5 checksum compare or non MD5.

If I try to checkout all four of the Missing files, I get two alerts prompting me to merge the files.  I say no, the files are now on my local file system and the status is back to where I started - two files listed as "Unknown".

---

Craig's update:

You're definitely on to something.  I moved each of the duplicate items to another directory.  That immediately solved the issue in that I now could checkout the four items (two in same dir and two in new dir) without any "Unknown" items.  I then deleted the two items that I moved to the new directory.

In doing this, I saw some more info.  We somehow have a directory structure like this:

```
Parent_Dir
--SubDir1
--SubDir1
--SubDir1
--SubDir1 <- Two items were here
--SubDir1 <- Two items were here
--SubDir2
--SubDir3
--SubDir4
--SubDir5
```

Somehow we have five sub directories with the same name and these two files in question existed in two of the sub dirs with the same name.

The issue appears to be resolved.  Do you think I should manually delete the extra sub directories?

---

Thanks to Craig this issue appears resolved.  I have no idea how this situation was created (anyone?) but..  we're good now.  Thanks Craig!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It would be a huge mistake to delete the files before you determine where the problem lies. Deleting and re-adding the file would kill the history and any links to the file. It also might not fix the problem, due to the way that StarTeam works internally (with a Native-II repository, anyway). Deleting the file and re-adding the identical file will not actually update anything in the repository, except the pointers to that revision. The revision itself would have stayed there when you deleted the file, and re-adding it would just create a new pointer to that revision.

If you haven't done so already, I strongly recommend telling StarTeam to calculate the file status using an MD5 checksum. Do this in the client via Tools->Personal Options->File->Use file checksums to calculate status. Then try update status again. This is not the default setting (in at least some versions of StarTeam), so it's worth checking. If you have not already done this, it may, by itself, fix the problem.

The first thing to do is to determine if the revision is valid on the server. If the files are text, the easiest way to do that is to compare contents between that revision and the previous revision. If it does turn out that the revision is corrupt, then the best solution would be to check out an earlier revision, and then force check in. This way you preserve the history of the file.

If the file appears to be OK on the server, then test it locally, by comparing contents. If the file is corrupt locally, do feel free to delete the file locally and then check it out again. Unlike deleting the file on the server, you don't lose anything by doing this, except local revisions.

If these suggestions do not fix the problem, I still would not recommend deleting the files on the server. Tell me the results of your investigations back here, and we'll see where we can go from there. It is, in my opinion, nearly always mistake to kill history.

### Update

Based on the updated information in the post, I'm getting a better sense of what is going on here. It is likely that there are two items which point to the same file, and have the same name. "Item" is a concept in StarTeam related to the fact that a single file, change request, requirement, etc. can live in multiple places at once. For example, you can have a single file in two different views or projects.

Generally, you do not have the items with the same name in the same folder. But it can happen. And that probably explains the "Unknown" status. When you tell StarTeam to compare the file on disk with the item of the same name on the server, perhaps it can't figure out which item it should look at.

The first thing I would try is to try and drag one of the two items somewhere else. If that fixes the problem in the folder in question, you can delete the item elsewhere, without affecting the item in the folder. If, on the other hand, dragging one of the items elsewhere causes them both to move, it's easy to drag the item(s) back to where they came from.

### Update 2

> Do you think I should manually delete the extra sub directories?

Yes, but just as with the files, move them first, and make sure the subdirectories you'd like to keep are unaffected before deleting them.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response Craig!  I tried your suggestions but didn't have any luck.  I edited my post with the results..

Answer (score 2):

A good way to identify this issue if it comes up again is to click on the root folder, add folder path to the shown columns, then click the all descendants button.  Sort the files by name, and look for the unknown files and see if multiple files of the same name are checking out to the same path.  Usually this is the result of a mistaken share, addition, or a change in folder check-out path.

As it is undetermined what order StarTeam will check files out, having two different files with the same name pointing to the same local location is a mistake.  The 2005R2 native Windows client and Cross Platform client would pull files in a slightly different order, causing views with this issue to produce checkouts with different files.

There are a few ways to legitimately end up with this situation - keeping multiple branches of a single file on the tip and designating which to use by view label is a common one.  StarTeam is one of the few VCs that can handle multiple references like this.

Separately, if you can help it, never delete and re-add a file.  99% of the time, it isn't what you want to do.  Re-adding a file to the server gives it a whole new archive in the database and it will not be tied in any way to existing shares of that file.  You will also lose all of your revision history.  Instead, look for ways to move files.  And if you have multiple files with the same name and content on your server, it is usually a good idea to make an effort to share the file to the various places it should exist rather than re-add it.  This will make sure your changes propagate so you don't need to check-in fixes multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

Were those files added twice?  You can add the same file multiple times which could result in this error.  Also, check the Reference tab - are these linked files to elsewhere in the repository?

Answer (score 0):

Could that be the files or their status got corrupted on the server? In that case, delete and re-add is the only way.

Comment: Thanks Tom.  This happens semi-regularly.  We'd love to figure out why this happens and how to fix it when it does happen.

Comment: Find the pattern. Are they always same files? Are they binary files? Are they too large? If they are plain text what are the encoding methods (UTF-8), see if they are compatible with encoding method between client and server and etc.

Comment: I can't remember the details of the files when this happened in the past.  The current two files in question are text files (with a ".ready" extension).   We have a fair amount of other similar files in StarTeam without any issues.  They are 2K and 40K.